# What is filk music?

Tags: music, fans

I recently heard that there was a sci-fi related music form called "Filk."

What is Filk? Where can I find out about it?

Comment: isn't this kind of a list question, which seem to be not in the SE pov.

Comment: @benstraw I wouldn't call this question a list question or asking for recommendations, and am unsure why you retagged it as such.

Comment: And we're really not smarter than Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filk

Comment: @Wikis From now on, every question on this site should get at least one answer or comment linking to Wikipedia.

Comment: @nellius isn't he asking for a recommendation for where to find filk?

Answer (score 29):

Filk is music written and/or performed by SF fans, often on subjects related to SF or SF fandom. The term derives from a typo (for "folk music") in an SF convention programme book, back in the 1950s.

There's a pretty good introductory article [here](http://interfilk.org/?page_id=478).

You can find it by following other links on the website referenced above.

Comment: It wasn't actually a program book but an article submitted for a fan publication. see [Lee Gold's article](http://www.fanac.org/Fan_Histories/filkhist.html).

Answer (score 6):

To add to the previous answer, filk songs are often parodies of existing songs or take the music to a known folk song and write new, usually humorous lyrics to it. Since filking is often an informal event where everyone joins in the singing, using familiar music helps those participating get the song right, even if it is their first time singing the words. The songs are often fantasy or science fiction based, but not always.